# Need uploadcontrol in a ajax.beginform using asp.net mvc3 html5 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

I've been looking for a long time for this but I'm still stuck, I need to have an upload control where the user can upload a document and give additional information.

I've had to do this before without the upload control so what I do is I get an ajax.beginform that will give all the input from the user to the controller and than close the popup trough a onsucces function, so this looks like this:

view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Documents", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "CloseDialog" }, new { @class = "form-inline", id = "FormId" }))
{
    @Html.Label("Description", "Description")
            <div class="span3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
            </div> 

}
```

I tried adding there an Html.BeginForm but then I found out that it is not possible to use nested forms so I deleted this.

In my controller I have:

```
public PartialViewResult Index(string description)
{
     var model = new DocumentsModel{ Description = description};

     return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string description)
{
     if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
     {
         var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
         var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"D:\Documentds\"), fileName);
         file.SaveAs(path);
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index", new { description = description });
}
```

Ofcourse because the html.beginform won't work this controlleraction won't work either
So my question is how to do this without having to use a html.beginform?

Comment: Please provide a little more about your context. Where do you get nested forms? Also you seem to have mentioned some popup. How is it implemented?

Comment: I'll try to explain.
I have an application where the user gets an overview of all files on the server where they are saved and where they come from, these files have a description, and a few other attributes. This is all listed in a grid

The user can add new documents for this the user clicks on a button and then a pop-up opens (a partialview). In this partialview the user can fill in the description and other attributes. These are mostly textboxes that are contained by the ajax.beginform. He can also upload the document itself, a file from his computer that needs to be added to the server.

Comment: I tried to add a html.beginform (wich is a pretty easy way to add a uploadcontrol) however because the ajax.beginform this won't work.

Comment: Please show your code. It's hard to understand what you have tried. You cannot nest HTML forms nor use AJAX to upload files, but maybe showing your code will make your question more clear and I will understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I know I can not use ajax or nest forms, that is why I'm trying to find another way, that is my question.
I'll add code gimme sec

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the file upload inside the form and also the enctype="multipart/form-data" property on the form that calls uploadfile. That could be one problem.

Also, you could use JavaScript to submit the form you want from another part of the page without having them nested and keeping your design.